# ASP.NET MVC System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection Ambiguous Reference?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reference, asp.net-mvc-routing, ambiguous

I am trying to write a unit test for testing routes; however, the project is failing to resolve the RouteCollection. When I reference the dll (from the system and also by browsing to my MVC project) and use the FQN (System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection), it complains of an ambiguous reference.

On a side note, when looking at the intellisense for System.Web.Routing, every item is duplicated!

Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After using reflector to decompile the dll, I came to the conclusion that the RouteCollection did not exist in that dll. Turns out that it exists in System.Web